# Eloquent returns MSSQL data as strings rather then their respective datatypes

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, sqlsrv

**What am I using**

- PHP 7.3.8
- MSSQL Server 2016
- SQLSRV 5.8.1
- Laravel 5.8.23
- ODBC Driver 17

Mysql returns data with their respective datatypes so integers are actually integers, datetimes are datetimes etc...

Mssql returns data as strings rather then their respective datatypes.

**Tinker raw query: (example of data being returned as strings)**

```
>>> DB::select(DB::raw("select * from pallet_labels where id = 1"))
=> [
     {#3090
       +"id": "1",
       +"crop_date": "2019-08-14",
       +"article_amount": "160",
       +"note": "seeded label",
       +"pallet_label_farmer_id": "1",
       +"made_by": "tomm",
       +"cell_number": "1",
       +"cell_description": "seeded label",
       +"harvest_cycle": "1",
       +"harvest_cycle_day": "1",
       +"created_at": null,
       +"updated_at": null,
       +"deleted_at": null,
       +"cell_id": "1",
       +"user_id": "2",
       +"farmer_id": "1",
       +"cultivation_cycle_id": "1",
       +"pallet_type_id": "1",
       +"status_id": "1",
       +"article_id": "2",
     },
   ]
```

I have found [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11780#issuecomment-415694128) whilst googling:

They are talking about adding these options to your *"config/database.php sqlsrv connection"*

```
'options' => array(
                PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
                PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_NUMERIC_TYPE => true
            )
```

However that changes nothing.
I do not want to use [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) as I believe this is not the answer

Comment: Is that tinker result with options set as described bellow (and after server restart after setting those options)?

Comment: Thats correct @Tpojka

Comment: Could it be some tinker thing (i.e. have you checked `is_int($result[0]['pallet_label_farmer_id'])`)?

Comment: No, I just used Tinkerer to give an example of what the data return looked like. I can reproduce this however ud want. I expect this to be related to the drivers @Tpojka

Comment: I want to say, maybe that's tinker way of standard output (tinker is just dev tool). If you get `is_int($result[0]['some_value_meant_as_int']) === true` then it's good.

Comment: Do I really have to post a dd, eloquent return, and an if(1 === $palletlabel["id"] to convince you that data is returned as a string. As I said it has nothing to do with tinker. The whole application is misfunctioning because data is returned as strings rather then their respective datatypes

Comment: As extra measure @Tpojka, here u go: dd(is_int($pallet[0]['id'])); return: false. That obviously would have been the expected result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211867/discussion-between-tpojka-and-tomm).

Comment: A possible explanation is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563747/laravel-pdo-settings).

Comment: @Zhorov the last sentence in my post says: I do not want to use attribute casting, this is like doing a double job. That would mean I would have to cast every column on every model to their original datatypes.

Comment: @Tomm I understand, sorry, I missed that part :).