# Laravel Big Integer returns string when converting to json

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using foreignId in my migration and it is converting to string, but primary key is working fine.

By the way I'm using Laravel 8, PHP 8

this is my migration

```php
Schema::create('tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
 $table->id();
 $table->foreignId('shop_id');
 $table->timestamps();
});
```

then if I want to convert this model to json

```php
$token = Token::find(1);
return response()->json($token, 200);
```

I will receive this

```
{
 id: 1,
 shop_id: "12",
 created_at: "2021-06-08T12:41:07.000000Z"
 updated_at: "2021-06-08T12:41:07.000000Z"
}
```

Comment: show some code so that some one can identify whats the issue

Comment: add your migration up method to your question

Comment: it's a pdo config issue, check this answer for how to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39478813/4369919 The property to set is ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES to false

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by enabling **nd_pdo_mysql** extension and disabling **nd_mysqli** extension in configuration.
Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your `shop_id` is a string but I guess your tokenController is saving the shop_id property as a string.

Anyway, if you want to make sure your Token model always return the `shop_id` property as an integer, you should tell your model to cast it to an integer.

**In your Token model, add the following line just after your class declaration:**

```
protected $casts = ['shop_id' => 'integer']);
```

See [Laravel Attribute Casting Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)

Answer (score 0):

you can make it with 2 solution

**Solution 1**
you can create resource and customize response

run
`php artisan make:resource TokenResource`

and in toArray funcation

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        "id" => intval($this->id),
        "shop_id" => intval($this->shop_id),
        "created_at" => strval($this->created_at),
    ];
}
```

and in controller

`$token = Token::find(1);` 
`return TokenResource($token);`

**Solution 2**
using stdClass

`$response = new \stdClass;` 
`$response->id = intval($token->id);` 
`$response->shop_id = intval($token->shop_id);` 
`return response()->json($response,200);`